# macOSで変換中の文字列を変換単位で分割して表示したい

Tags: swift, macos

macOS向けの独自のテキストエディタを作成しているのですが、日本語入力のときに
[image]
のように変換中の文字列を変換単位の単語語ごとに分割して表示する方法はどのようにすればよいでしょうか。この画像はmacの標準アプリのテキストエディットのものです。

NSTextInputClient, NSTextInputContext は一通り見てみましたが、この表示を実現できるAPIは見つかりませんでした。
NSTextView を使えばできると思うのですが、作成中の独自エディタは使用していません。

setMarkedText から得られる情報だけでは以下のように現在の変換ターゲットとそれ以外の二つにしか別れていません。。

[image: myapp]

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。